# Checking if a user exist in my database but I get no response from the local server when I send a request

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native

I have my SQL server running fine and I am able to connect to the database just fine. I have a node script that is expecting a user credentials. When I send a 'post' request, I do not get any response back for some reason. Than again I am new to node and react-native so I could be doing it wrong.

I believe there is another method with express Router which I have tried, but I did not have any chance with that. I checked to see if it was a database connection problem, but I don't think that is the case since I checked the connection and it's fine. I researched online for some solution, I notice that most people use express Router. With that method, I can't use app.listen(port).

This Code is in the userLoging.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/json'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'password',
    database:'LetsEat'
});

app.post('/api',function(req,res){
    var username = req.get.username;
    var password = req.get.password;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM USER_CREDENTIALS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?',[username,password],function(err,row){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }

        if(row.length > 0 )
        {
            res.send({'success':true,'message':row[0].username});
        }
        else
        {
            res.send({'success':false,'message':'User not found please, try again'});
        }
    });
});
```

This code is in the screens/Login.js file

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.state = {username:'',password:''}
  }

  login = () =>{
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username:this.state.username,
        password:this.state.password
      })
    }) 
    .then((res) => {
      if(res.success === true)
      {
        var username = res.message;
        AsyncStorage.setItem('username',username);

        alert("User exist");
      }
      else
      {

        alert(res.message )
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
    .done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.loginScreen}>
          <TextInput style={styles.input}
            placeholder = 'Email Address'
            onChangeText= {(username) => this.setState({username})}
            value = {this.state.username}
          />
          <TextInput style={styles.input}
            placeholder = 'Password'
            onChangeText= {(password) => this.setState({password})}
            value = {this.state.password}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login}>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

          <View style = {styles.newUserField}>
              <Text> New User </Text>
            </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click login (TouchableOpacity), I should expect an alert that either says 'user exist' or 'User not found please, try again'. Instead the alert I am getting is 'Invalid' This is what makes me think that I am not getting a response from the local server.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use **plain-text passwords**. Encrypting with [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) is not hard, and many Node packages can provide other, better solutions.

Comment: @tadman that's not the point, is the response that I am worried about for now. The plain text password will be dealt with later, it's not a priority.

Comment: These are things that should be done properly the first time so accidents don't happen. Code like this that "works" can end up running in production. Doing it properly is not time-consuming or hard. The real question I have here is if you can use an existing library like [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org) instead of whatever this is.

Comment: @tadman Alright, you have a point and it is being taken care off. In the mean time could you help me with my main problem please?

Comment: @PatrickAdjei you should just use [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/).  Your problem likely won't persist after you use it.